# Changing the color of the link on hover using stylesheets

Tags: pyqt

Hai all,

I don't know why the following lines of code isn't working. My aim is to change color of the text when the link is hovered..

```
self.syncFolderSelection_addFileTypesTextBrowserInTable.setStyleSheet("QTextBrowser:hover{color:#00ff00;background-color:#ff0000;}")
```

The BG color chages without any error but the foreground color is not. Can anybody correct me..

Comment: Is it the same color as the original?  :P

Comment: This is just a try to change the color.. But in real i want the link color to become red when it is hovered.. Any suggestion??

Answer (score 0):

The `QTextBrowser` displays HTML source, so if you want to change the color of links in the HTML, add `<style>` tags with your updated styles to the HTML source before sending it to the `QTextBrowser`.

Comment: Thanks jcoon for your reply.. But can u show me a minimal example?? I couldn't understand this..